# A/B Test: t-test vs. chi-squared test

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

I am working on a marketing campaign analysis between treatment-A and treatment-B. The goal is to find which treatment yields more clicks. Say, I have one month of experiment duration and at the end I want to determine if one treatment is statistically better than the other. I can formulate the problem in two ways:

1. t-test: I find the average daily click rates of A and B, and then perform a t-test.
2. chi2 test: I find the total clicks of these A/B treatments at the end, and perform a chi2 test.

Can someone comment on the differences of these two approaches?

Comment: You should include more tags, to attract a wider audience. Also, seeing as you haven't got any responses yet, try asking your question here on cross-validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Can you be more specific about how exactly you propose to perform the chi-square test in your setting?

Comment: If $p_A$ is the proportion of clicks generated by treatment $A$, have you considered testing $H_0:p_A=\frac{1}{2}$ versus $H_1:p_A \neq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @fedja For chi-squared test, I have the number of visitors for treatment A, the number of clicks under treatment A, the number of visitors for treatment B, and the number of clicks understand treatment B. Then the H0 is the two treatments yields the same result. Then use stats.chisquare() to get p-value.

Comment: @AdamRubinson what additional tags should I add?

Comment: @David293836 it doesn't matter much any more- you've got an answer now. I added the "statistics" tag, but otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: @MatthewPilling What test would you use to do that?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Please review my comments to the answer below and provide your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: The test statistic for this hypothesis would be the $z-$score $z=\sqrt{n}\Big(2\hat{p}_A-1\Big)$. Here, $\hat{p}_A$ is the (observed) proportion of clicks generated by treatment $A$ and $n$ is the total number of observed clicks. This test would only be appropriate if you observed at least ten clicks generated by treatment $A$ and treatment $B$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thanks. But isn't a z-test similar to a chi-squared test? My main issue with z-test and chi-squared test is that they assume normal/gaussian distribution of the data.

Comment: The $t$ test also assumes normal distribution of data. If you're counting the number of clicks generated by various treatments then you're never going to get anything that's perfectly normal. You didn't specify what kind of $\chi^2$ test you plan on implementing in your hypothesis test, and using a normal approximation to the binomial distribution (which is where the $z$ test comes from) is perfectly acceptable as long as you have at least ten clicks generated from each treatment.

Comment: If you don't want to utilize normal approximations for the binomial distribution you could calculate the $p$ values directly using $\text{binomcdf}$ on the hypothesis test I suggested. If you want to use the $t$ test and you don't want to assume that "number of clicks per day" is approximately normal then you would have to have a sample size of at least $n=30$ (meaning you observed clicks for at least $30$ days) to safely perform the $t$ test

Comment: @MatthewPilling My issue is that one does not really know the distribution of the samples with the Chi-squared test approach. In my description above, one has the following 4 numbers: treatment A clicked, treatment A not-clicked (or total treatment A count), treatment B clicked, and treatment B not clicked (or total treatment B count). Without knowing their distribution, the error from chi2 or z-test is unbounded. With t-test and using the daily rate averages, the data is Gaussian and t-test would work well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119961/discussion-between-matthew-pilling-and-david293836).

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means a statistician, so what I write below is just some common sense advice.

The Student test is the canonical way to go for the mean comparison, but it relies on having a few samples from each of the two distributions. If you have a long streak of clicks, then you are welcome to split it into several subsets *but* you need to be reasonably sure that the distribution is *the same* and approximately normal within each subset. The splitting into days is very questionable because it is hard to justify that the people clicking habits do not change from day to day. As to myself, when I come home after a work day and go to the web, I definitely do not want any stupid ads, but on weekends I may be more benevolent if I'm in a really good mood. The Student test is robust in the sense that if you do *any* splitting (of course, decided upon in advance and without looking at the data) and it shows statistical significance, then it is, indeed, there. But if you split into subgroups with different underlying distributions, then your empirical variance may be a noticeable overestimate of the true variance and you lose sensitivity, so if the change in the clicking means from day to day is comparable to or greater than the difference in overall means between design A and design B, with daily averages you'll detect nothing even if the difference is there. Approximately normal is usually not a problem as long as you have not too few members in each subset.

So, if you have a timestamp on, say, users' entering the page, I would definitely go for Student, but I'd split differently. I would partition the whole observation period into 10 minute intervals and within each interval assign 1 minute to each group (I would even rotate or randomize that assignment from one 10 minute interval to another). That will give me more groups to estimate the variance and I will be way more sure that the underlying distributions for different groups are the same. By the way, I would also do it to compare the daily means in this way, and, if I see that there, indeed, exists a significant difference between them, request that the observations be complemented by two missing days of the week before doing any analysis because the natural human life cycle is a full week, not 5 days (just make sure that you don't hit holidays, etc.)

What to do if you don't have the timestamps but only the daily totals? Then, as I said, you may still perform Student and if it shows the difference, it will be there, but if it doesn't, then you may just suffer from the effect I described. So in this case I would go for a quick and dirty version of $\chi^2$.

Note that the original Pearson $\chi^2$ test is designed for a *different* situation that you are in (just look up the assumptions and the setup on the Wikipedia page or in a textbook), so I doubt you can run it the way you intend with a meaningful result. However, we can get something similar from the first principles. Suppose that $A,B$ are the total numbers of users reached and $X,Y$ are the corresponding numbers of users who clicked. You want to know if the difference has occurred by pure chance or not. If you accept that all users and design effects are the same and there is some underlying probability $p$ to click, then the distribution of the vector $(\frac{X-Ap}{\sqrt{Ap(1-p)}},\frac{Y-Bp}{\sqrt{Bp(1-p)}})$ should be approximately standard 2D normal and, in particular,
$$
\frac{(X-Ap)^2}{Ap(1-p)}+\frac{(Y-Bp)^2}{Bp(1-p)}
$$
would have the $\chi^2$ distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. Since you don't know $p$, you have to take the infimum over it, so your actual statistics is
$$
\inf_{p\in(0,1)}\left[\frac{(X-Ap)^2}{Ap(1-p)}+\frac{(Y-Bp)^2}{Bp(1-p)}\right]
$$
This is not exactly $\chi^2$ but it is concentrated better than $\chi^2$, so you still can use the $\chi^2$ table for it. When $A,B$ are not to small and the probabilities to click are not too close to $0$ or $1$, this approximation is fairly good. This is robust too (in the above sense) and will also suffer from the loss of sensitivity if the probability to click depends significantly on the day or on the user group, but it is still better than Student with a bad partition (though worse than the Student with a good one).

Just my two cents. Comments from people who know better are invited :-) (Questions from people who know worse too).

Comment: Great answer. Just curious as to why you didn't suggest the two sample proportion hypothesis test $H_0:p_A=p_B$ versus $H_a:p_A \neq p_B$ which has test statistic $$z=\frac{\hat{P}_A-\hat{P}_B}{\sqrt{\bar{P}(1-\bar{P})\Big(\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}\Big)}}$$ where $\hat{P}_A=\frac{X}{A},\hat{P}_B=\frac{Y}{B},$ and $\bar{P}=\frac{X+Y}{A+B}$. What is the benefit of the $\chi^2$ test over this one?

Comment: @MatthewPilling I'm not very good in such matters, so it took me some time to figure out how reliable that is for really small probabilities (I compared with the surely safe binomial test where you have $\alpha={A+B\choose X+Y}^{-1}\sum_{x,y:x+y=X+Y,{A\choose x}{B\choose y}\le{A\choose X}{B\choose Y}}{A\choose x}{B\choose y}$. It turns out to be a decent approximation (20% relative accuracy in $\alpha$ unless you are paranoid about making it small) in the standard rule of thumb area $\min(X,Y)\ge 10$ (I assume $X<A/2,Y<B/2$), so I was going to add it to my post today but you were faster :-)

Comment: @fedja FYI, from the data I have seen, the weekday purchase rate is about 20% higher than that of weekend. Additionally, if you split data into 10 minute groups, you'd get much higher variance because the the purchase rate varies widely in the 24 hours of the day.

Comment: @David293836 You misunderstood the idea: In each ten minute interval one minute goes to each of ten groups (say, the first minute to the first group, the second to the second, etc.) That averages the intraday fluctuations. Of course, they are wild, so consecutive splitting makes even less sense than the daily one, you are perfectly right about that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @fedja. If I understand you correctly, you also agree that t-test with daily split is better? And maybe split into weekday and weekend test? Note that for each day, I have at least thousands to 10s of thousands of samples for each treatment.

Comment: @fedja Regarding chi squared test, a number of sources actually suggested the method I described above. An example can be found in Khan Academy's online course: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/chi-square-tests/chi-square-goodness-fit/v/chi-square-statistic

Answer (score 0):

- I'll start with the chi-squared test. You said you want to compare the total clicks at the end. But wouldn't this depend on how many people visit the sites that were using treatment A versus treatment B? If treatment A only had 250 visitors and all of them clicked, it would probably be better than if treatment B had 1000 visitors and 500 clicked. So you might be interested in comparing the proportion of clicks. Say you have the following data after one month:

```
clicked   A    B
yes       500  500
no        600  650
```

Would you say that A is the same as B? Probably not, because more people visited the site under treatment B and it had less of a click rate. At this point, you can do a 2-proportion test or a chi-square test to compare if there is a difference between treatment A and treatment B in terms of getting people to click. They are the same test. Here is how you would do it using a 2-proportion test.

**Hand-calculating the z test statistic**

```
AY=500
BY=500
AN=600
BN=610

#prop test calculation
p1=AY/(AY+AN)
p2=BY/(BY+BN)
phat=p1-p2
ppooled=((AY+AN)*p1+(BY+BN)*p2)/(AY+AN+BY+BN)
zstatistic=phat/sqrt(ppooled*(1-ppooled)*(1/(AY+AN)+1/(BY+BN)))
zstatistic^2
pnorm(zstatistic, lower.tail=FALSE)*2
```

-out

```
> zstatistic^2
[1] 0.03739652
> pnorm(zstatistic, lower.tail=FALSE)*2
[1] 0.84666
```

So we get a p-value of 84%, suggesting there is no difference between the two proportions. (This is not too surprising, because I constructed the proportions to be quite close together.) The square of the z-statistic that we just computed is actually the chi-squared statistic, as we will see later on.

**Using the prop.test command**
We can also directly use the built-in prop.test command.

```
prop.test(c(AY, BY), c(AY+AN, BY+BN), correct=FALSE)
```

-out

```
    2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  c(AY, BY) out of c(AY + AN, BY + BN)
X-squared = 0.037397, df = 1, p-value = 0.8467
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.03740849  0.04559850
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.4545455 0.4504505
```

From the third line, you can see that the chi-sq test-statistic (which is the square of the z-test statistic) and p-value both match from previously.

**Chi-squared by hand**
Now here is how to do the chi-square test by hand. Note that it is exactly the same test as we have just previously done. The effect of it is to compare the observed data to what we would have expected if there is no difference in treatments. That is, it compares the first table with the following table, called the expected table.

```
Expected
clicked  A          B
yes      497.7376   502.2624
no       602.2624   607.7376
```

The code is as follows

```
#chi-squared test calculation
tab=data.frame(clicked=c("yes", "no"), A=c(AY, AN), B=c(BY, BN))
rate=(AY+BY)/(AY+BY+AN+BN)
AYE=rate*(AY+AN)
ANE=AY+AN-AYE
BYE=rate*(BY+BN)
BNE=BY+BN-BYE
chisqstatistic=(AYE-AY)^2/AYE+(ANE-AN)^2/ANE+(BYE-BY)^2/BYE+(BNE-BN)^2/BNE
chisqstatistic
df=1
pchisq(chisqstatistic, df, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

-out

```
> pchisq(chisqstatistic, df, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.84666
> chisqstatistic
[1] 0.03739652
```

**Chi square test command**
Or, using the built-in command, we get

```
> test=chisq.test(tab[,2:3], correct=FALSE)
> test

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tab[, 2:3]
X-squared = 0.037397, df = 1, p-value = 0.8467

> pchisq(test$statistic, df, lower.tail=FALSE)
X-squared 
  0.84666
```

- The difference between the preceding chi squared test and the prop test is the for the prop test, you can specify a one-sided hypothesis. So you could test if the proportion for B is greater than A or vice versa.
- You also say conduct a t-test for average daily click rates. So I presume you mean you would take the sum of the click rates and then divide by 30, giving you the average clicks per day? Again, I'm not sure this is a good idea because the visits to the sites for treatment A and treatment B may not have the same traffic and be directly comparable. However, if we were to assume that they have exactly the same traffic, it is conceivable you would be able to conduct a t test to test the difference in means for any measurable quantity, such as clicks per day. So you would have a sample of clicks per day under treatment A and treatment B and compare the means of those samples. This is conceivable, again, if treatment A and treatment B experience the same traffic.

### Conclusion

The two methods you propose are fundamentally different. One tests if there is an overall difference in the **proportion of clicks** garnered by treatment A versus treatment B and can be conducted if there is a difference in number of sites visited under treatment A and B. The other method requires that the number of sites visited under treatment A and treatment B are the same and then compares the **clicks per day** of the two treatments.

Comment: Let me add more classification of t-test. First, the goal of the experiments is to determine if a treatment is better than the other statistically. For example, if treatment A yields an average click rate of 0.22 and treatment B yields an average click rate of 0.25. Is 0.25 significantly higher than 0.22 statistically? That is the goal. Having said that, let me state how I do t-test in the next comment block.

Comment: Say we have 30 days of performance data. I can compute the daily average click rate and come up with a sequence for treatment A like (A1, A2, A3, .... A30) and another sequence for treatment B as (B1, B2, B3, ... B30), where Ax and Bx are numbers between 0 and 1. Then I can use t-test to determine if A sequence and B sequence are statistically different. This is how I would do t-test. Let me explain why I prefer t-test over chi-squared test in the next comment block.

Comment: A reason I prefer t-test is that by taking averages and form a sequence out of them, one can assume the data form a Gaussian distribution due to Central Limiting Theorem. Both t-test and chi-squared test assume data are drawn from Gaussian distributions. However, one cannot assume the total numbers of clicks needed in chi-squared test are from Gaussian. So I assume that t-test is better. Does my logic make sense? Or it is flawed? Comments are welcome.

Comment: A chisquared test for independence in between treatment A and B in a contingency table does not require a normality assumption. You would just need to record the total number of clicks and the total number of **not clicks**. It cannot be normal because you are counting frequencies. I am in fact not sure how you would conduct a chisquared test on the "total number of clicks." The t test is also valid. It sounds like the t-test uses the central limit theorem on 30 daily click rates. Overall, it boils down to if you want to compare the proportion of clicks versus the daily click rate.

Comment: I think the chi squared test directly tests if there is a difference in click rate. After you do the chi squared, which only tests for any difference at all, you can do a **one-sided** t-test to see if the better one is statistically significant. It sounds like for a t-test, you would be comparing daily click rate. But it can be argued that this is the same as overall click rate. So just think about if you prefer a procedure that calculates the overall click rate or one that calculates the daily click rate and then compares the average of those.

Comment: I think both are valid if the traffic to the site is evenly spread out throughout the month. One problem with the t test is that if one day had a lot of clicks (say 5000 out of 6000), it would not receive any more weight than a day with fewer clicks (say 1 out of 2) if you just took the average of the daily click rates. They would be represented as 5/6 and 1/2 respectively and you would lose information if you directly took a simple average.